# ORY Hydra introspect token from external client

Tags: oauth-2.0, token, hydra

I managed to setup ORY Hydra in a docker container and first tests show that it is working fine. Especially, I can issue an access token for a client and also later introspect that token using the hydra command line interface. I can even introspect the token with a simple HTTP request from a shell on the docker host machine, like:

```
curl -X POST -d 'token=Gatyew_trJ8rHo0OEqPU6D6a5-Zwma79ak7KffqT7rA.U7F43t5o0ax_qdj9EBFS8ulR2R1GaCzkaiFPAIE-5d4' http://127.0.0.1:9001/oauth2/introspect
```

where I use the published port of the introspection endpoint.

Now when it comes to introspect the token with the same curl call from a **different** machine, like

```
curl -X POST -d 'token=Gatyew_trJ8rHo0OEqPU6D6a5-Zwma79ak7KffqT7rA.U7F43t5o0ax_qdj9EBFS8ulR2R1GaCzkaiFPAIE-5d4' http://snowflake:9001/oauth2/introspect
```

the introspection is denied due to missing authorization. This is also indicated in the hydra log. Note that the same call works when issued from a shell in the docker host machine itself, even without authorization. But called from a different machine, the call is denied, even when I use (testwise) basic authentication, like

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic some-consumer:some-secret" -d 'token=Gatyew_trJ8rHo0OEqPU6D6a5-Zwma79ak7KffqT7rA.U7F43t5o0ax_qdj9EBFS8ulR2R1GaCzkaiFPAIE-5d4' http://snowflake:9001/oauth2/introspect
```

(Note that the hydra server is by default configured for basic authentication only).

What would I have to do to be authorized to introspect the token with a call from a **different** machine? And how and why can hydra distinguish the two identical calls (either from the docker host machine or from the other machine) and recognize the one as authorized and the other not?

Answer (score 0):

Found it: I had to pass the client-id:client-secret base64-encoded, then it works.

Create a bearer token:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic c29tZS1jb25zdW1lcjpzb21lLXNlY3JldA==" -d "grant_type=client_credentials" http://snowflake:9000/oauth2/token

8SVvB9PTyvGU-td4-VH3BcRMquUFMWG_umFyzQaKAMo.vJfXfIUDzNmmcMqa4_HExREdcmU7iW4CqK9v_qN4Jdg
```

Introspect the token:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic c29tZS1jb25zdW1lcjpzb21lLXNlY3JldA==" -d "token=8SVvB9PTyvGU-td4-VH3BcRMquUFMWG_umFyzQaKAMo.vJfXfIUDzNmmcMqa4_HExREdcmU7iW4CqK9v_qN4Jdg" http://snowflake:9001/oauth2/introspect

{"active":true,"client_id":"some-consumer","sub":"some-consumer","exp":1612965583,"iat":1612961983,"iss":"http://snowflake:9000/","token_type":"access_token"}
```

But I still wonder why the introsection request works on the docker host machine without the Authorization header.